# iOS5，presentModalViewController presenting new view incorrectly

Tags: objective-c, ios5, presentmodalviewcontroller

My app mainly supports iOS6+. When considering about iOS5, I added the following judgement.

```
 if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 6.0) { 
    self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
    [self presentViewController:readerViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
 }
 else {
    self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
    [self presentModalViewController:readerViewController animated:YES];
}
```

However, the modal view presents vertically in my landscape app. I mean, my app is landscape, **the modal view just "lies" there, not fullscreen as I set, just cover part of screen while the uncovered is black.**

I wonder if anyone could help. Thanks in forward.

Answer (score 1):

Lilac :- What tia said is correct. you dont need to worry about the version.I think you haven't set the Orientation for the ModalView with the required view Oreintation.

Means, if your mainViewController (from which you are presenting ModalView) is supporting only Landscape Mode then in the modalViewController, you have to set the Orientations, restricting to present in Landscape View only.

You should write the Orientation code written in mainViewController also in the modalViewController.

these Methods :-

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
    //    return YES;

}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

Kindly revert if it does not solve your problem and if it does help, you know what to do ;).

Comment: I do have the methods you mentioned upstairs and this problem is the stretch of the autorotate issue not long before. The parent view supports landscape and modal view all orientations. In iOS6+, I present a modal view from its parent view and it works fine. While in iOS5, the problem comes out. If it's not the version problem, what else problem can it be? Can you think of it?

Answer (score 0):

First, `presentViewController:animated:completion:` has been available [since iOS 5.0](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController%3aanimated%3acompletion%3a) so you do not have to worry about the version. In case if you really want to check the availability of the method, you should use

```
if ([self respondToSelector:@selector(presentViewController:animated:completion:)])
```

For the modal view, you need to set `modalTransitionStyle` and `modalPresentationStyle` on *presented controller* e.g. `readerViewController` in your case. So your code should be

```
readerViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
readerViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
[self presentModalViewController:readerViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Comment: Your way do present the modal view. But what's importance is that it just "lied" there, not fullscreen as I set. I also tried                             [self.presentingViewController presentViewController:readerViewController animated:YES completion:NULL]; while it didn't work.

Comment: Maybe I missed some details? The parent view supports landscape and modal view all orientations. In iOS6+, I present a modal view from its parent view and it works fine. While in iOS5, the problem comes out. If it's not the version problem, what else problem can it be? Can you think of it?